# Not able to use npm in WIndows

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-8.1, npm-install

[Error message in cmd.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gSF7.png)

Hi
I'm not able to use npm on Windows 8.1 64bit. It shows the error message as in image link. I have installed nodejs v5.7.1

ERROR MESSAGE:
**'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.
3.6.0**

Tried changing PATH variables and installing a fresh copy in a different drive also

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, just did that

Answer (score 2):

Download [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html)

Launch Cygwin Terminal as Administrator, then run the following command

`curl -L "https://npmjs.org/install.sh" | sh`

This will do a fresh install of NPM. It could take a while to download but once the install completed if everything was successful, the last thing printed will be `It Worked`.

---

**EDIT: Changed from npm-windows-upgrade to Cygwin**

Comment: Thanks @peteb, But Im th following error when I'm trying to follow the steps.

ERROR MESSAGE:

Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: Make sure you're running powershell and cmd as an administrator

Comment: Yes, I'm using it as an administrator.

Comment: Thanks but nothing seems to work, not even this, Really, not able to figure out where problem actually is.

Comment: @DeepakKumarJain Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling node?

Comment: Yes, I have done that too. Also, tried installing it in a different drive as well.

Comment: See if [this link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3601) helps. The very last post on the issue from robertbaker

Comment: thanks **peteb** for all the help. Unfortunately none of these worked and the only solution that worked was that I formatted my system. Now nodejs and npm works like a charm. Thank you again so much.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your environment variables and on the system variables section remove the ComSpec variable

Answer (score 0):

First delete this two folders

- `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm cache`

Then delete the `Comspec` system variable.

It works definitely on windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

solution is very simple...open advance windows system settings
next....edit environment variable..in that...open system variable..in that...change comSpec value o C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe...then press OK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).